# How to get gcc's search path for Ada specs

Tags: c, gcc, ada, gnat

**Basic Question**:

How can I get `gcc` to tell me where it searches for `Ada` includes?

**Specific Problem**:

I have just finished converting a `C` library's header files to `Ada` specs so that I can interface with the library using `Ada`. I now want to install the specs on my system. I also want to make the installation portable to some extent so that I can `make install` on any machine (and thus host the specs and `Makefile` on [Github](http://github.com) or similar). I'm just not sure where exactly to install the specs to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gnat ls -v` will give you the default search paths.

If you want to install your own Ada library, you should place a project file (.gpr) in the "Project Search Path", which will tell gnat where to find the ada and ali files and the library.

Normally, you will place the ada files in `/usr/[local/]include/myadalib` and the ali files in `/usr/[local/]lib/myadalib` and maybe link the .so file into `/usr/[local/]lib`, but you can put them anywhere you want. The important thing is to place the project file (myadalib.gpr) in the project search path.

You can even adjust the project search path by setting the ADA_PROJECT_PATH environment variable.

Comment: OK, cool. Is there a simpler way (for example, without a project file) for the case where it's just a couple of `.ads` files which define the interface to a library written in `C`? Or do they still need to be built into .ali files.

Comment: You still need the .ali files and the library, if you don't want to provide the full source (.ads and .adb) or don't want the "user" to compile the Ada binding. You still have to provide some of the .adb files, for example generic packages need them. IMHO every library or binding should provide its own project file. Makes everything a lot easier.

Comment: So are you saying that I need to provide a `.so`/`.a` for the Ada spec itself, or are you referring to the library I'm binding to? Also, I don't have any .adb files; just .ads for the binding.